# Losing data in dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have 2 lists that I am merging together like this, is there a way to merge without losing data because I have duplicates in the code?

```
new = dict(zip(sortedPrimes, a))
```

both sortedPrimes and 'a' are lists with 1062 elements when I use len(). However when I zip them together like this when I print len(new) I get 336. This hasn't happened before, where is the data going?

Rest of the code:

```
def rwh_primes(n):
    sieve = [True] * n
    for i in range(3,int(n**0.5)+1,2):
        if sieve[i]:
            sieve[i*i::2*i]=[False]*int((n-i*i-1)/(2*i)+1)
    return [2] + [i for i in range(3,n,2) if sieve[i]]

numbers = rwh_primes(10000)

a = [x for x in numbers if x > 1000]

final = []
sortedPrimes = []
for x in a:
    sortedPrimes.append(''.join(sorted(str(x))))

lisp = [x for n, x in enumerate(sortedPrimes) if x in sortedPrimes[:n]]
new = dict(zip(sortedPrimes, a))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a situation where one key is mapping to multiple values. In that case, one reasonable data structure is a dict of lists:

```
import collections

d = collections.defaultdict(list)
for v1, v2 in zip(sortedPrimes, a):
    d[v1].append(v2)

for k in sorted(d):
    print k, d[k]

# Output   
0013 [3001]
0014 [4001]
0017 [7001]
0019 [1009, 9001]
0023 [2003]
0034 [4003]
0035 [5003]
0047 [4007]
0059 [5009]
0067 [6007]
0079 [9007]
0089 [8009]
0112 [1021, 1201, 2011]
0113 [1013, 1031, 1103, 1301, 3011]
0115 [1051, 5011, 5101]
etc. for all 336 keys ...
```

Answer (score 3):

```
print(len(set(sortedPrimes))) # Count of unique keys: 336
```

Dictionaries hash values to keys. Those key aren't duplicated. There's 336 unique items in sortedPrimes so there's 336 keys in new

Comment: How am I able to merge them without losing any of the duplicates?

Comment: @PoChenLiu - by not turning them into a `dict`?

Comment: Yes. If you don't want to lose them you could use nested tuples:
new = list(zip(sortedPrimes, a))
That will retain the list lengths.